# How do I install Steam 64-bit when package dependencies cannot be resolved?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 64-bit, dependencies, steam

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.10 on Wubi, and am trying to install Steam.

Notably, when I am trying to "buy" steam from the store, it reads

> **Package Dependencies cannot be resolved**
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a
> conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
> installed at the same time.

Opening the details shows this:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> steam64: Depends: steam (= 1.0.0.26) but it is not going to be
> installed

I've read online that I need to update Ubuntu 12.10.  I have done both methods, both using Software Update and the manual update (via `sudo apt-get update`/`upgrade`).  Everything's up to date, and yet I cannot install Steam.

Any fixes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`steam64` is just a virtual package for the i386 `steam` package of the same version.

By default, x64 Wubi (and normal?) installs don't have i386 support enabled, which is required by the `steam` package.  To enable it, you can do this at a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

As of this writing, the `steam` and `steam64` debs in the software center are out of date (1.0.0.26) and contain Beta warnings.  These warnings have been removed in the .deb on the Steam site (1.0.0.27).

Answer (score 3):

All right, I've figured this out.

What you need to do before trying to download Steam is to [**update your system**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).  You can do this two ways, either by going to the top left hand corner and clicking the dashboard icon and then searching for Update and using it; or, manually:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Afterwards, **do not** install Steam from the Ubuntu Software Centre.  It is extremely buggy, and in most cases will not work for you.  (I had everything up-to-date in terms of update, yet it kept giving me the same problems.

Install steam from its homepage: [**Steam**.](http://store.steampowered.com/about/)  You should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the Ubuntu Software center, then go to

> edit>Software Sources

Check the options:

- Downloadable from internet
- like main
- restricted
- universe
- multiverse

Go to tab Other Software and check canonical partner,and indepedent software. 
Go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steam64
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```