# Dependency problems installing steam

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, steam

I'm having some dependency trouble trying to install steam on Ubuntu 14.04. I got the steam-launcher.deb-Package from http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb and installed it:

```
eva@eva-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg --install steam_latest.deb 
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket steam-launcher wird gewählt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 196920 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von steam_latest.deb ...
Entpacken von steam-launcher (1.0.0.49) ...
steam-launcher (1.0.0.49) wird eingerichtet ...
Trigger für gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Trigger für mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Trigger für man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) werden verarbeitet ...
```

Starting steam gives the following:

```
eva@eva-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ steam

(gnome-terminal:4881): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
```

and opens a new terminal window with

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for eva: 
.................................................................................................................
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Hängt ab von: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3)
 unity-control-center : Hängt ab von: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) soll aber nicht installiert werden
                    Hängt ab von: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Fehler: Unterbrechungen durch pkgProblemResolver::Resolve hervorgerufen; dies könnte durch zurückgehaltene Pakete verursacht worden sein.
Press return to continue:
```

After closing the additional terminal window, inside the first I get:

```
Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed
Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed
Package libc6:i386 needs to be installed
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1424305157)
[2015-03-07 12:14:01] Startup - updater built Feb 18 2015 15:31:44
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2015-03-07 12:14:01] Checking for update on startup
[2015-03-07 12:14:01] Checking for available updates...
[2015-03-07 12:14:02] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1424305157, installed version 1424305157
[2015-03-07 12:14:02] Nothing to do
[2015-03-07 12:14:02] Verifying installation...
[2015-03-07 12:14:02] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2015-03-07 12:14:05] Verification complete
[2015-03-07 12:14:07] Shutdown
eva@eva-ubuntu:~/Downloads$
```

It also pops up a window saying I'm missing the 32-bit version of libGL1.so.1. and tries to start steam, which fails.

Previously I also did

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

as proposed by [How do I install Steam 64-bit when package dependencies cannot be resolved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256271/how-do-i-install-steam-64-bit-when-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved).

I don't have any PPAs installed, my current `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
eva@eva-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)]/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Somehow, the whole situation looks kind of ridiculous, because the two libcheese packages already seem to be installed, shown by `dpkg -l | grep libcheese`:

```
ii  libcheese-gtk23:amd64                                 3.10.2-0ubuntu2                                     amd64        tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam - widgets
ii  libcheese7:amd64                                      3.10.2-0ubuntu2                                     amd64        tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam - base library
```

Maybe the error happens because those are not 32bit?

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, just a simulation, nothing will actually happen -

`sudo apt-get -s install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386`

If it looks ok then re-run the command but remove the `-s` to actually install

If it is questionable or fails then post the terminal output, either here in your question or in a pastebin like - http://paste.ubuntu.com/ or http://pastebin.com/ & add link to your question

Comment: worked for me as well.  lots for me to learn about ubuntu.  seems like the package you suggested is specific to ubuntu and the problem package is more generic.