# Problem installing Steam in a fresh installation

Tags: 14.04, steam

I have just re-installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to install Steam.

This is what I get

[image]

After using

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get

[image]

After waiting for some days the official link from Steam worked again (because it didn't work before) so I downloaded the `.deb` package and tried to install it.

Every time I press the Steam icon it produces the next message

[image]

so I try to install them but the installation never completes as I get

[image]

What is that now and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install steam on a 64bit system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/257084/how-do-i-install-steam-on-a-64bit-system)

Comment: @Zacharee1 I was always installing Steam the same way but now out of the blue it tells me that I have broken packages in a fresh installation!

Comment: Yes, and that duplicate gives you the solution.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Why suddenly the usual way doesn't work? Its not like I was using a 32 bit and I changed it now in 64 bit.

Comment: Another package may have added the 32-bit architecture before.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I just tried it...I get exactly the same message.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/588024/steam-install-error-on-14-04-ubuntu-64bit

Comment: try downloading the steam package from steam directly and see if that works, the one in the repos fails with these kind of errors on 14.04.03(maybe 14.04.04 as well)  I pulled out my hair for hours trying to get it to work.

Comment: @TrailRider I tried it at the beginning and I got a forbidden link.

Comment: not sure what that could be.  `sudo apt-get install steam:i386` should work but installs it in a way the steam doesn't like much so it may complain.  It will pull in the correct graphic stack depends.  you can then uninstall and then install via the steam package and all you depends will already be installed and it should work(or you can leave it installed as is with a few strange issues.  see my Q&A for more info.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/661932/unable-to-install-steam-in-14-04-03-dependency-problem-updated-this-should

Comment: I was able to use the steam package to install it correctly later so I was hoping that would avoid the long way around that I found but I guess not... the solution I found should work but the posts are long b/c the issue was such a PITA

Comment: @Zacharee1 not a dupe of that question, that does not work, I can tell you form personal experience. might be a dupe of mine, but only if the solution works for the OP, still waiting to hear.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/661932/unable-to-install-steam-in-14-04-03-dependency-problem-updated-this-should

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 32bit architecture to Your system

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For Your 2nd issue, please do:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Following @TrailRider comment, please try to change mirror of Your repositories or try to generate new ones, You can use this web to speed things up:

https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same message :/

Comment: but `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and `sudp apt-get update` went OK?

Comment: There was one message that I will put it in my question as an image.

Comment: Please check my updated post.

Comment: Nothing changed, I get the same messages.

Comment: this likely not help even with the edits, there has been an issue with steam from the ubuntu repos with 14.04.03(not sure about .04)  for some reason it tries to pull  packages from the wrong graphic stack so it will not find the newer packages and will fail with depend. issues.

Comment: If you still get the "W: Failed to fetch ... Hash sum mismatch" error, try and select a different repository mirror as described here: http://askubuntu.com/q/53084/367990

Comment: Yes, that said, other repos may help, You can try generate new ones as well here: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/