# Steam needs to install these additional packages

Tags: 14.04, package-management, steam

Hi i have annoying problem with steam in ubuntu. After running steam it showed me that error:

```
    Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
..........................................................W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

And I want to add that i am new to linux(i spend like 14 years with Windows and few days ago i changed it to Ubuntu) so i dont know everything perfectly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/593798/dependency-problems-installing-steam

Answer (score 0):

Your update settings have your CD-ROM files enabled. So every time it tries and updates it automatically looks for those files, which by definition are outdated. Just unselect the cdrom option and:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

should run normally [without CD-ROM install files selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj3df.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/689368/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04.3 this worked for me perfectly.

```
sudo apt-get install steam -y
```